# Scala giving me "illegal start of definition"

Tags: scala

I'm trying to get started with Scala and cannot get out of the starting gate.

A file consisting of the line

```
package x
```

gives me

> error: illegal start of definition

Regardless of what x is and regardless of where I put the file (I had a theory that I had to place the file in a directory hierarchy to match the package definition, but no).  I get the same error with the example code from the web site and with the REPL.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to declare the `package` membership in a Scala script (run using the `scala` command) or in the REPL.

Only files defining just classes and objects which are compiled with `scalac` may be defined as belonging to a package.

When you run code in a script or a REPL session, behind the scenes it is actually compiled inside a method of an object, in which scope a package declaration wouldn't be legal.

Comment: So how then would you run the code from the 'examples' folder of the scala download archive? Most of them have a ``package examples`` line and the contents sticks to the rules I believe. I can ``scalac`` them, but running them with e.g. ``scala -classpath . sort`` gives me a ``java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError``!?

Comment: @ThomasH 

    >scalac ScalaFileWithPackageLine.scala 

    >scala fully.qualified.name.of.topLevel.ScalaObject

Answer (score 28):

Since Scala 2.11.0-M7 you can use `:paste -raw` (fix for issue [SI-5299](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5299)). This option allows defining packages in the REPL:

```
scala> :paste -raw
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

package Foo

class Bar

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.


scala> import Foo._
import Foo._

scala> new Bar
res1: Foo.Bar = Foo.Bar@3ee2cf81
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I've resolved it by importing `import packageName._` instead of declaring a worksheet in the package.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when I was executing scala program eg. *"Game.scala"* from terminal.

Compiling part was ok, error was shown when running the code, see below

#### ☐ Wrong:

```sh
user@pc:~$scala Game.scala
/home/$USER/.../src/ul/org/bloxorz/Game.scala:1: error: illegal start of definition
package ul.org.bloxorz
```

Scala code should be invoked from terminal pretty much the same as Java code (you should give it a fully qualified class name and not the file name like I did in first example)

#### ☑ Correct:

```sh
user@pc:~$scala ul.org.bloxorz.Game
```

Answer (score -4):

I don't get this error. How are you compiling this? And, by the way, what web site? As for REPL, it doesn't accept packages. Packages are only for compiled code.

Comment: Wow, it literally *never* occurred to me that the compiler and the interpreter might have different command names.  I was thinking of Python and using scala instead of scalac.

"What web site?" -- I was about to answer http://www.scala-lang.org/ but I went and checked: the example code was from (the excellent) http://max-l.github.com/Squeryl/ (qv).

You may know begin making those little doy, duh, durp noises you like so much.

Comment: I have same error: I'm in this folder: https://github.com/Sergey80/scala-samples/tree/master/src/main/scala/partial_function .

trying do this: scala PartialToReal.scala

Comment: This is more like a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @DavidGriffin It answered the REPL part, which was answerable.