# Access package private method in Scala REPL

Tags: scala, private, read-eval-print-loop

Suppose I have a `private[stuff]` method `Stuff.something` in `org.my.stuff`. Is there something that I can do in the Scala REPL so that I can call `Stuff.something` without getting the error `error: value something is not a member of org.my.stuff.Stuff`?

In particular, can I get the REPL to be "inside" a given package (here `org.my.stuff`), giving access to its private members?

Comment: Well... `private` things mean that they are `private` and there is nothing that you can do about it. But more important is that you `should not` be trying to do that.

Comment: You can add some code in the same package and call that using REPL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I read a private field in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196192/how-do-i-read-a-private-field-in-java)

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh correction, I mean `private[stuff]`; editing

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh, I think that's a bit overstating it. It would be good to have a way of doing it from the REPL, under controlled conditions. In the final code, I agree with yout.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Using "packages" in the REPL

You cannot get a REPL prompt "inside" a given package, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2632303/8261

You can use "package" statements inside "`:paste -raw`" mode in the REPL (see e.g. http://codepodu.com/paste-mode-in-scala-repl/ for docs)

For example, if you had code like:

```
package org.my.stuff {
  object Stuff {
    private[stuff] val something = "x"
  }
}
```

You could declare a helper class in the same package using "`:paste -raw`" mode, i.e.

```
scala> :paste -raw
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

package org.my.stuff {
  object StuffAccessHelper {
    def something = Stuff.something
  }
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.


scala> org.my.stuff.StuffAccessHelper.something
res11: String = x
```

### How to access any members using `setAccessible`

You can always fall back on the full "`setAccessible`" reflection incantation, as described at [How do I read a private field in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196192/how-do-i-read-a-private-field-in-java)

Using the same prior code as above, you can access `org.my.stuff.Stuff.something` like:

```
scala> val f = org.my.stuff.Stuff.getClass.getDeclaredField("something")
f: java.lang.reflect.Field = private final java.lang.String org.my.stuff.Stuff$.something

scala> f.setAccessible(true)

scala> f.get(org.my.stuff.Stuff)
res10: Object = x
```

Comment: A `private[stuff]` method in scala is compiled to a public method, because the JVM doesn't have such finegrained access modifiers like scala. And also, you can define packages in the REPL with `:paste -raw`.

Comment: Thanks, @Jasper-M, I've updated my answer accordingly