# Is it possible to extend a package private class defined in a 3rd party jar in Scala

Tags: scala, package-private

Is it possible to extend a package private class in scala that is defined in a 3rd party jar. So for instance if a 3rd party jar that my code depends on has some class like so

```
private [somepackage] A {

}
```

can I somehow subclass this class in my code?

Thanks

Comment: i assume you mean `private [somepackage] class A`?

Comment: You can write your own code in `somepackage` to access `A` and make it public to allow it being accessed from your main package. But note that this will run into trouble once Scala works with Java 9 module system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not according to *Programming in Scala 3rd Ed.*, paraphrased:

```
package a
package b {
  private[a] class B
}
```

> all code outside the package `a` cannot access class `B`

Note that here, package `b` is in package `a`.

Curiously, this doesn't appear to be the case in the REPL: see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42068129/access-package-private-method-in-scala-repl)

Answer (score 1):

Nope, you can't do that.

If you need it to stub/mock it, consider using a proxy to access class A, and stub/mock that proxy class instead. E.g., if A.doStuff is what you want to mock/stub, and A.accessStuff is what you need in your code, create a class

```
class ADecorated(underlying: A) {
  def doStuff() {
    underlying.doStuff()
    // whatever I want to do
  }

  def accessStuff() {
    x = underlying.accessStuff()
    // do something else and return
  }
 // Any other method you want to use
}
```

Replace usage of `A.createA` with new `ADecorated(A.createA())`. `ADecorated` is what you work with now